# Converting string to date in another culture

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert a string (which represents date in invariantCulture) to dateTime in given culture.  The problem is that when the date is converted to German culture, the day becomes month and month becomes day. 
What is wrong with below code or am i missing something ?

```
var day = 11; var month = 12; var year = 2014;

var someDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
var theDay = someDate.Day;//11 ok as expected
var theMonth = someDate.Month; //12 ok as expected

var dateString = someDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var date1 = DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-De"));
var day1 = date1.Day;//12 this should be 11 ?
var month1 = date1.Month; //11 this should be 12 ?
```

Comment: Can you provide the dateString please? I.e. what is it in your debugger?

Comment: you are formatting your date using `InvariantCulture` and then parsing it using different culture...

Comment: debugger shows dateString as 12/11/2014 00:00:00

Comment: This would only work if `de-De` and `InvariantCulture` use the same format. `Parse` with `InvariantCulture` instead.

Comment: A `DateTime` has no "culture" or "format", it just has a value. So this question is pointless. If you instead ask how to format a `DateTime`as `string` in a different culture, then it useful.

Comment: It makes no sense to take a DateTime, convert it to a string, and then back to a DateTime.  That is just useless code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument to `DateTime.Parse` is used to tell the parser what format the string is in, not what format you want to convert it to. You are generating an invariant string and then parsing it as a German string which is why your day and month are getting swapped.

If your goal is to get a German string representation of the date, just use `var dateString = someDate.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess `de-De` culture doesn't have a standard date and time format as `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

Since you using [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ToString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), result string will be [`"G"` standard format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) which is  `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` for `InvariantCulture`.

Because of that, `dateString` will be `12/11/2014 00:00:00` and `de-DE` culture doesn't have a standard date and time format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` but has `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` which is `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss` for `de-DE` culture.

That's why [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) method matches pattern which is `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` (since it's [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) is `.` it should be `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss` format).

That's why it parses your `12` as a `Day` and `11` as a `Month`.

If you already a `DateTime` (which you have) just use `.ToString()` method with your `de-DE` culture like;

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("de-De");
var dateString = someDate.ToString(culture);
```

Remember, a `DateTime` doesn't have *any* implicit format or culture. It just have date and time values. `String` representations of them can have formats.

By the way, you can find all standard date and time patterns your `de-DE` culture like;

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("de-De");
foreach (var format in culture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns())
{
    Console.WriteLine(format);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line and test it again:

```
 var dateString = someDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

to:

```
 var dateString = someDate.ToString("O");
```

or:

```
 var dateString = someDate.ToString("S");
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is what i think what you want to accomplish, not sure if i got you right: you want to read an invariant cultured date string and convert it to a german cultured date string.
but in your example you are trying to parse an invariant cultured date AS a german cultured date. of course that leads to a misinterpretation. try this:

```
string invariantCultureDateString = "12/11/2014 00:00:00";
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(invariantCultureDateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string germanCultureDateString = dateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-De"));
```

BR